# Most efficient structure of mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, database-design

I'm curious what the best way to structure my mongoose Schema is. I'm making a movie site with the User schema set like this:

```
let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    watchlist: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed],
    seen: {
        like : {
            type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]
        },
        dislike: {
            type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]
        }
    },
});
```

When a user clicks either a thumbs up or thumbs down icon, an object of

`{movieID: movieID, title: movieTitle, poster: moviePoster}`

will be sent to the like or dislike array in the seen property. I'm going to use this info in my EJS template to determine if a movie has already been seen and if seen and liked then gray out the dislike button and if seen and disliked gray out the like button. I also want to be able to remove the item from seen if the use clicks a 'clear' button. In order to do that it seems like I'm going to have to loop over both arrays in order to determine if the movie is included in one and then remove it. Seems like there has to be a better way to do it. I was thinking of structuring the 'seen' object using the movieID as a key, like this:

```
seen: {
  '123': {
    movieID: '123',
    title: 'movieA',
    poster: 'movieA-poster.jpg',
    like: true
  }, 
  '456' : {
    movieID: '456',
    title: 'movieB',
    poster: 'movieB-poster.jpg',
    like: false
  }
}
```

But when I try to send the data to seen using .findOne and this function:

```
const movieObj = {
  id: req.body.movieID,
  title: req.body.movieTitle,
  poster_path: req.body.poster_path,
};

User.findOne({_id: req.user._id}, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {

    user.seen[req.body.movieID] = movieObj;
    user.save(function(){});
  }
}
```

I still just get an empty object returned to me. I changed the schema seen object to:

```
seen: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {} }
```

and have set {minimize: false}, because I read that mongoose by default doesn't allow empty objects. Appreciate any guidance on what I'm doing wrong or if you have a better way to efficiently structure the schema to allow seen movies to easily be added or removed from the db.

Comment: Reference Link that help you, How to use populate : https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think mongoose populate will help you here.
Just read about it, you will get a good idea about it.
Here is a good link with an example:

https://hashnode.com/post/how-do-i-successfully-populate-a-mongoose-schema-cj339r6kt004g5mk83ycujilq

Answer (score 1):

Please look this Models and queries that can help you do build your **schemas**.

1.**User Schema**

```
let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    watchlist: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed],
    like : [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], //remove
    deslike : [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], //remove
    seen : [{
    movieId : { type:  : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,  ref: 'Movie' },
    isStatus : {type : string} //Enum [like,dislike,'seen']
}]
})
```

2.**Movie Schema**

```
let movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    tile: {
    type: String
  },
  description: { type: String }
})
```

3.Data store in Both Table

/*user*/

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5acaf0589ff6bfb5dd091f"),
"seen" : [ 
        {
            "movieId" : ObjectId("5b9e2544953b5f69683059d4"),
            "isStatud" : "like"
        }, 
        {
            "movieId" : ObjectId("5b9e2544953b5f69683059d6"),
            "isStatud" : "dislike"
        }, 
        {
            "movieId" : ObjectId("5b9e256d953b5f69683059ee"),
            "isStatud" : "seen"
        }
    ]
        "like" : [ 
            ObjectId("5b9e2544953b5f69683059d4"), 
            ObjectId("5b9e256d953b5f69683059ee")
        ],
        "deslike" : [ 
            ObjectId("5b9e2544953b5f69683059d6")
        ]
    }
```

/*movie*/

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b9e2544953b5f69683059d4"),
    "title" : "movie1",
    "description" : "desc1"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b9e2544953b5f69683059d6"),
    "title" : "movie2",
    "description" : "desc2"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b9e256d953b5f69683059ee"),
    "title" : "movie3",
    "description" : "desc3"
}
```

Query to get users by movie

/*This is working fine and tested*/.

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([{
    $match : { _id : ObjectId("5b5acaf0589ff6bfb5dd091f") }
    },
    {$lookup : {
        from : 'movie',
        localField : 'like',
        foreignField : '_id',
        as : "likes"
        }},

        {$lookup : {
        from : 'movie',
        localField : 'deslike',
        foreignField : '_id',
        as : "deslikes"
        }}

    ])
```

/*Query with group*/

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([{
    $match : { _id : ObjectId("5b5acaf0589ff6bfb5dd091f") }
    },
    {$unwind : '$seen'},
    {$lookup : {
        from : 'movie',
        localField : 'seen.movieId',
        foreignField : '_id',
        as : "seen.movieData"
        }},
    {$unwind : '$seen.movieData'},
    { $group: { "_id": "$_id", 
              "name" : { "$first": "$name" }, //use same all other field of user
              "seen" : {"$push" : "$seen"}
               } ,
                }
    ])
```

Please check and let me know any help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So this was my third thought, to just list the movie in both a seen and then a like or dislike array. Would having that information listed in the database twice cause any speed or performance issues, since I'm basically just duplicating data?

Comment: Is like or dislike default as seen?

Comment: Update my answer with `seen` Please check